# Big Oh from function

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm having a lot of trouble finding big oh for the function:

> $$f(i)=i+2i+\cdots+i\cdot i,$$

where $f(i)$ is the steps to run this function. Could you give me a hint as how to find it?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
f(n) = n+2n+\dots+n\cdot n = n\sum_{k=1}^n k = n\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2} 
$$

Comment: Thank you. What is the intuition for this (from sigma to the end)?

Comment: Usually, the intuition is to try to $\sf(a)$ look at the first terms to find some sort of pattern, or even plot the first 1000 terms to see what the shape "looks like" (this gives you a hint about what you should *hope* to prove); and/or $\sf(b)$, attempt to *simplify* the expression as much as possible: here, there was a $i$ ($n$ in my notation) present everywhere, so it was sensible to factor it; and the remaining factor then was the sum of the $i$ first integers, $(1+2+\dots+ i)$, for which we know a closed-form expression (a fortiori an approximation).

Comment: also, knowing this closed-form expression $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ helps; but in general, for big-oh, it is enough to recall that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^\ell = \Theta(n^{\ell+1})$$
To remember it: just do the parallel with integration: $$\int^x t^\ell dt = \Theta(x^{\ell+1})$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have is $f(i) = \sum_{j=1}^i ij = i\sum_{j=1}^i j = i\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$. This follows from the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, you can write the function in a compact form as
$$ f(i)=i+2i+\cdots+i\times = i( 1+2+\dots+i )= i \frac{i(i+1)}{2}. $$

Now, notice that

$$ \frac{i^2(i+1)}{2}\sim \frac{i^3}{2}, $$

as $i\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not precise. Big Oh question depends on whether you are looking for $i\to \infty$ or $i\to 0$. Since $f(i) = \frac 12 i^3 + \frac 12 i^2$,

[Case 1] $f(i) = O(i^3)$ as $i\to \infty$ since $\lim_{i\to \infty} \frac{f(i)}{i^3} = 1/2$.

[Case 2] $f(i) = O(i^2)$ as $i\to 0$ since $\lim_{i\to 0} \frac{f(i)}{i^2} = 1/2$.

Comment: As $i$ is an integer, considering $i\searrow 0$ doesn't really make sense in this case.

Comment: @ClementC.You are right.